# django field datetime set auto_now_add = true but mysql error field has no default value

Tags: mysql, django

I have this field in my model:

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

but when I try to save data to mysql with this command:

```
INSERT INTO unprocessed(provider_id, record, type )  VALUES (1, 1, 1);
```

this error appear:

```
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value
```

I searched the INTERNET but i couldn't find a way to solve it

Comment: Django does not impose `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` on database level. It is implemented on application level. Django simply assigns value to field before saving to db. So database itself wont do anything if you manipulate it directly with sql query.

Comment: @NafeesAnwar as I got form your answer I cannot test with this query, thus how can I test it?

Comment: There can be several solutions. I don't know proper context of your problem but if you only want to do it for development / production, you can run query `ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY COLUMN <colname> DEFAULT dafault_timestamp;
`

Comment: Django will just work fine with it. but never insert data using default value (set by db) in production. Many complicated things related to timezones can/will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Nafees Anwar is right. If your class name is unprocessed, maybe you can use this way like

```
tmp = dict(provider_id=1, record=1, type=1)
data = unprocessed(**tmp)
data.save()
```